# Unity button works even "if" is false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I was trying to do a shopping system but my buttons worked even if statement were false. I put  10 < 5 on purpose but if statement still executing the code.
[Method for button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO0Xz.png)

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUYYt.png)

Comment: Pls consider posting the code here instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as @kar mentioned please feel free to post actual code samples so others can help. Secondly, when dealing with logical expressions ( ||, &&, etc.) please note that these have an order of operation/precedence like you would see in Mathematics (BODMAS).

e.g. The below code will always execute what's inside the IF block because the state is not 0. If the state was 0, then it would not execute.

```cs
if( state!=0 || state!= 1 && 10 < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Logic needs to be fixed.");
}
```

To be clearer it's also recommended to group logical operations instead of relying on implicit ordering e.g. by changing `if( state!=0 || state!= 1 && 10 < 5)` to `if( state!=0 || (state!= 1 && 10 < 5))`

Comment: Thank you. I think my mistake is order. Ill check it now.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged the statement like this and get state parameter direclt on object. It did the trick. thank you again Onboardmass
[correct statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT7tt.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead copy the code into the answer itself. This will solve several issues. There is no link that can break and the code can be found via search